# Cleaner way of creating a new object after using Object.values()?

Tags: javascript

What is the cleaner way of performing this operation?

```
let formContext = {};
Object.values(screenContext).forEach(
  (s) => (formContext = { ...formContext, ...s })
);
```

so I want to build a new object from the values of another object

Comment: Are all properties of `screenContext` an obj?

Answer (score 3):

You can spread it into `Object.assign`:

```
const formContext = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(screenContext));
```